# handling apollo-server errors on client

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, apollo-server

**What I'm you doing?:**

I would like to thrown an error on apollo-server and process it on client.

**Note:** I'm using apollo-link-error middleware on apollo-client.

**Server:**

```
import { UserInputError } from "apollo-server";

 Mutation: {     
    someMutation : { 
     try {
       // here is some code which failed
      } catch (error) { 
// base Error class has message property by default 
// response just hold some additional informations 
       throw new UserInputError(error.message, { response });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Client:**

simplified implementation of my mutation on client

```
    <Mutation
       mutation={CREATE_ORDER}
     >
        {(createOrder, { loading, error }) => (
        ....
         try {
           await createOrder({  variables: {...}});
         } catch (createOrderError) {
          //  here I get Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
            console.log(createOrderError);

          }

         )}
   </Mutation>
```

I receive following error on client (in **catch clause** in the code above):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at Mutation._this.onMutationCompleted (react-apollo.browser.umd.js:631)
    at react-apollo.browser.umd.js:586
```

This error looks like problem with **httpLink**.

**Response**: (from network tab in chrome dev tools)

[image]

From graphql spec :

> If an error was encountered during the execution that prevented a
>   valid response, the data entry in the response should be null.

So I assume that my response from server is valid. The data object should be null.

**What do I expect to happen?:**

I would like to access to response from apollo server How could I achieve this?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Things to check before accessing the data returned from query or mutation

1. If loading -> return some loader component
2. If error is present -> display some error component

If not any of above two conditions matched then for sure you have the data.

Apart from that you need to have

1.**On Apollo Client ["errorPolicy"](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/error-handling.html#policies)**

```
 const client = new ApolloClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      watchQuery: {
        errorPolicy: 'all'
      },
      query: {
        errorPolicy: 'all'
      },
      mutate: {
        errorPolicy: 'all'
      }
    },
    link,
    cache,
    connectToDevTools: true,
  })
```

**2.For customising error sent from server -**

You can use `formatError`

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  ...root,
  resolverValidationOptions: {
    requireResolversForResolveType: false,
  },
  formatError, <---------- send custom error
  formatResponse: (response, query) => formatResponse({ response, query }),
  dataSources,
  context: async ({ req, res }) => {
    const user = req.user;
    return { user, req, res };
  }
});
```

e.g

```
const formatError = (error) => {
  const { extensions } = error;
  logger.error(error);

  const exception = extensions.exception ? extensions.exception : {};
  logger.error('\nStackTrace');
  logger.error(exception.stacktrace);
  exception.stacktrace = null;
  const extractedError = extractErrorFromExtention(extensions);

  return extractedError || { message: error.message, code: extensions.code, exception };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but problem was with apollo-link-error middleware

Comment: @Morty can you elaborate your solution? I am running into the same issue within a test with MockedProvider

Comment: Update: some underlying error is not correctly thrown, thus only visible in the browser console but not in server tests. errorPolicy does not change anything